# Perl Database connect not working in .pm file

Tags: mysql, perl, soap, dbi

In Perl I have connected the database using DBI concept. The database connection and select table query is working fine in .pl file. But I have run the DBI database connection code in .pm file. It's not working.

Please review code.

Sample.pl (It's working fine)

```
use DBI;
my $driver = "mysql"; 
    my $database = "marketplace_perl";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
    my $userid = "root";
    my $password = "root";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password );
    my $dbh=connect_db();
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserEmail,UserPassword FROM pj_user where UserEmail=? and UserPassword=?");

        $sth->execute($UserEmail,$UserPassword);
```

Marketplace.pm (It's not working)

```
package Marketplace;
use DBI;
    sub connect_db {
        my $driver = "mysql"; 
        my $database = "marketplace_perl";
        my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
        my $userid = "root";
        my $password = "root";
        my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password );
       return $dbh;
    }

    sub login_marketplace { 

    my $dbh=connect_db();
            my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserEmail,UserPassword FROM pj_user where UserEmail=? and UserPassword=?");

            $sth->execute($UserEmail,$UserPassword);
            my $User_count=$sth->rows;
    return $User_count

    }
```

It returns the error message of **"Failed to access class (Marketplace): Can\'t locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module)"**

Please let me know how to fix the DB issue.

Comment: KLooks like DBI is not installed

Comment: @Jens It's already installed.

Comment: @Jens the database connection working in normal perl file. If it's DBI not installed how it's working normal .pl file

Comment: Where is the DBI.pm located?

Comment: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1

Comment: And is that directory in the `@INC` of whatever program is trying to use your module?

Comment: @Shawn. No. I have used only use DBI.  You mean to use do "File/DBI.pm" method ?

Comment: No... Is that directory in the `@INC` of whatever program is trying to use your module? If, say, you're trying to run it with a different version of perl than you were using for your first program, it might not be.

Comment: Please provide the FULL error message, and the path to `DBI.pm` (`/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1/DBI.pm`?)

Comment: @ikegami the full error message is 

"'Failed to access class (Marketplace): Can\'t locate DBI.pm in atINC (you may need to install the DBI module) (at INC contains: /var/www/kane/CGI-bin) at /var/www/kane/CGI-bin/Marketplace.pm line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/www/kane/CGI-bin/Marketplace.pm line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 104) line 1.
"

Comment: Something in your program corrupted `@INC`.

Comment: Is this on a shared hosting environment or a virtual server? Does it by any chance run cpanel?

Comment: Reopened. The problem isn't that the module isn't installed. That said, there's no information from which to proceed, so voting to close for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code in marketplace.pm file.

```
use ENV;
my $PERL5LIB= $ENV{'PERL5LIB'};
 package Marketplace;

BEGIN {
 push(@INC, $PERL5LIB);
};
use DBI;
sub connect_db {
my $driver = "mysql"; 
my $database = "marketplace_perl";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "root";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password );
return $dbh;
}

sub login_marketplace { 

my $dbh=connect_db();
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT UserEmail,UserPassword FROM pj_user where UserEmail=? and UserPassword=?");

$sth->execute($UserEmail,$UserPassword);
my $User_count=$sth->rows;
return $User_count

}
```